# How do I accumulate the output of a function onto a list in streamlit so that the list persists?

Tags: streamlit

Streamlit dumps all objects every time it is run. Any interaction even will trigger this dump. Streamlit allows for function caching. What I need is a bit less than function caching.

What I would like to do is accumulate points evaluated by a function triggered by a user interaction:

```
points = []

setting = st.slider("set the value",value=5,min=1,max=10)
points.append([setting, func(setting)])

st.write(points)
```

Ideally, I gradually accumulate points as the user interacts.  This seems like it should be possible.  How does one do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SessionState hack:

```
import SessionState
session_state = SessionState.get(points=[])


setting = st.slider("set the value", value=5, min_value=1, max_value=10)
session_state.points.append(setting)

st.write(session_state.points)
```

Source for SessionState: https://gist.github.com/tvst/036da038ab3e999a64497f42de966a92

Discussion: https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/preserving-state-across-sidebar-pages/107/15

More recent work on multi page apps - https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/multi-page-app-with-session-state/3074